# I added dependency on pom file but do not have effect

Tags: eclipse, maven, servlets, jboss

When I compiled Java EE with JBoss, some configuration file said:

> jboss Cannot find class file for javax/servlet/ServletContext

So, I added the dependency in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But, it does not have any effect. It still could not find the `javax.serlet.ServletContext` package in my pom dependency.

Only when I added the "spec pack" in my including path, it works.

I use Eclipse, anyone know why this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `javaee-web-api` dependency:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you but actually the dependency should be:<dependency>
       <groupId>javax</groupId>
       <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
       <version>6.0</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>

Comment: Thanks for the note. I missed the fact that you're using J2EE appserver, so it should really be `javaee-web-api`.